# Image height is stretched in IOS for Ionic 5 app

Tags: css, ios, image, ionic-framework, ionic5

In my Ionic 5 app, I am facing a problem with image size for IOS. I am simply displaying an image on an `ion-card`. The potrait images are fine but not the landscaps.

HTML:

```
<ion-card>
<ion-row class="ion-justify-content-start">
<img [src]=path alt=""/>
</ion-row>
</ion-card>
```

SCSS:

```
img {
    max-height: 70vw;
    border-radius: 10px !important;
}
```

The expected result is the following. The browser and android is showing the correct size.
[image]

Following is the IOS image. The height is stretched out.
[image]

**EDIT:**
I checked by changing the `scss` property as per suggestions but the issue is not with img `scss` properties but the `ion-row`.
I put one image inside and one outside ion-row with no scss tag and the following is the result. Image outside the ion-row is just fine.

```
<ion-card>
<img [src]=path alt=""/>

<ion-row>
<img [src]=path alt=""/>
</ion-row>
</ion-card>
```

[image]

So ion-row is behaving differently in IOS.

Comment: Could you try to set `img { width: 100%; }`?

Comment: Hi @johannchopin, that didn't work. Please check my edit updates.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding ,

```
img{
max-width: 100%; 
height: auto;
}
```

If you are trying to apply the image to max-height of 70vw , then it will get stretched , either your orginal image should be of that height or alternatively you can apply the height to a parent container and set the image as a background image.

Something like this ,

```
.img-wrapper{
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 70vw;
  background: url('IMAGE_PATH') no-repeat center top;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

Comment: Hi @Koushik, thanks for your reply. Could you please check my comments on the post edit?

Comment: Hi @TapasMukherjee can you try enclosing the image in <ion-col size="12"> inside <ion-row> , possible to place the code in some online editor so that i can try debugging?

Answer (score 0):

I found that the issue is because of the combination of `ion-row` and `img` tags. When I use `img` tag inside an `ion-row` my image is getting stretched and sometimes not aligned properly only in IOS. I have tested the same in different IOS versions and it's the same for all. I do not know why this is happening but as a workaround, I replaced the `ion-row` with `div`, and it's working perfectly. If anyone else is facing the same issue you can try the same workaround.